# Reloading data from yml file on runtime after changes [Spring boot]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I load some data from yml file (this is not application.yml) to my spring boot app.
Now I would like to add functionality to reload data from my yml file after every change in this file.
What is the best way to do it?

Comment: is your question how to detect if this file is changed or not ? or how to reload?

Comment: updating application.yml/.properties means reload application, most of these properties are for starters (think about port number for example) What you are looking for is a separate properties file, juste make a listener on it ...